# Calculte indefinte integral of $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+2)(3-x)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to calculate $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+2)(3-x)}}$$.

I tried to use -

$\int u'v = uv - \int v'u$, but im pretty stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Multiply out $(x+2)(3-x)$, complete the square, then use trigonometric substitution.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4510170/442 posted today.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** rewrite the integral as
$$
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\frac{25}4-\left(x-\frac12\right)^2}}
$$
then substitute $\frac52\sin(u)=x-\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+2)(3-x)}}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2+x+6}}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{25}{4}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=x-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\text{d}u=\text{d}x$:

---

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{25}{4}-u^2}}\space\text{d}u=\int\frac{2}{5\sqrt{1-\frac{4u^2}{25}}}\space\text{d}u=\frac{2}{5}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4u^2}{25}}}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $s=\frac{2u}{5}$ and $\text{d}s=\frac{2}{5}\space\text{d}u$:

---

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\space\text{d}s=\arcsin\left(s\right)+\text{C}=\arcsin\left(\frac{2u}{5}\right)+\text{C}=$$
$$\arcsin\left(\frac{2\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{5}\right)+\text{C}=\arcsin\left(\frac{2x-1}{5}\right)+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

We need $(x-3)(x+2)<0\iff-2<x<3$

Set $x=-2\cos^2y+3\sin^2y\iff x-3=-5\cos^2y,x+2=5\sin^2y$

$dx=?$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+2)(3-x)}}
=& \ \text{sgn} (\frac12-x)\int \frac{d\left(\sqrt{(x+2)(3-x)}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{25}4- (x+2)(3-x)}}\\
=& \ \text{sgn} (\frac12-x) \sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac25 \sqrt{(x+2)(3-x)}\bigg)+C
\end{align}

Comment: Interesting that this should be equivalent to other arcsine representations

Comment: @FShrike - indeed equivalent, less known though

Answer (score -1):

You can $u$-substitute $u=x-1/2$ to get

$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{ (u+5/2)(5/2-u)}} = 
\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{25/4 - u^2}} $$

and trig substitutions take it from there.  You get the idea to let $u = x-1/2$ because the average of $2$ and $-3$ is $1/2$ and it makes the factors more symmetric.