# $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\alpha)(\beta-x)}}$ in two different methods gives two different answers. Where am I wrong?

Tags: integration

Hello I am new to Stack Exchange so please consider my mistakes regarding text formatting and other stuffs.
Here's my problem :$$I=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\alpha)(\beta-x)}}$$
My approach:
**method 1**
Put ${\sqrt{(x-\alpha)}=z}$ therefore ${(x-\alpha)=z^2}$
and ${dx=2zdz}$

Now

$$\begin{align}
I=&\int\frac{2zdz}{z*\sqrt{\beta-\alpha-z^2}}\\
=&2\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{\beta-\alpha-z^2}}\\
=&2\sin^{-1}\frac{z}{\beta-\alpha}+c\\
=&2\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\beta-\alpha}}+c
\end{align}$$

**method 2**

Put $\sqrt{\beta-x}=z$, then, ${\beta-x=z^2}$ , therefore,  $dx=-2z dz$

Now
$$\begin{align}
I=&-2\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{\beta-\alpha-z^2}}\\
=&-2\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{\beta-x}}{\sqrt{\beta - \alpha}}+c
\end{align}$$

Where am I wrong?
Edit:- writing mathjax is very time consuming (as a student who doesnt know to code)It took me at least 30minutes to write so i used stepjumping (sorry) How do you guys manage to write so much bigger equations?

Comment: Your formatting has gone awry at the end there. Welcome. With integration problems I generally find it very useful to put all your work on Desmos, graphing every step, so when something goes wrong you can point point exactly where it went wrong, visually

Comment: Why do you thing your two answers are different?  (The two values of $c$ merely differ by $\pi$.) Actually, they are both solutions of $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\alpha)(\beta-x)}}\tag1$$ since you have some signs wrong.

Comment: what signs wrong @GEdgar I dont understand.Plz elaborate.

Comment: To check an answer, differentiate it with respect to $x$.  In both Method 1 and Method 2, we confirm that you have evaluated $(1)$ and not the original integral.

Comment: yes @GEdgar Thanks for your comment , I actually wrote the question wrong in hurry Thank you But how the two answers be same

Comment: are the graphs of these two functions coincide in the domain of x if we shift one to another ?@GEdgar

Comment: how do you know these two values of c differ by \pi brother @GEdgar

Comment: Yes GEdgar is an extraordinary mathematician but that does not mean i cant address him 'brother' it is a expression of fraternity @Sourav Ghosh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
I_1 = 2\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{x-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\beta-\alpha}},
\\
I_2 = -2\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{\beta-x}}{\sqrt{\beta - \alpha}}
$$
The two answers differ by a constant, which is interesting.  We assume $\alpha < x < \beta$.  Let us write
$$
\theta = \arcsin \frac{\sqrt{x-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\beta-\alpha}},
$$
so that
$$
\sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt{x-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\beta-\alpha}},
\qquad0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} .
$$
Then $I_1 = 2\theta$.  What is $\cos\theta$?
$$
\cos^2\theta = 1-\sin^2\theta = 1-\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}
=\frac{\beta-x}{\beta-\alpha}
\\
\cos\theta = \sqrt{\frac{\beta-x}{\beta-\alpha}}
\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right) = \sqrt{\frac{\beta-x}{\beta-\alpha}}
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta= \arcsin\sqrt{\frac{\beta-x}{\beta-\alpha}}
\\
-\pi+2\theta= -2\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{\beta-x}{\beta-\alpha}} = I_2
\\
-\pi+I_1 = I_2
$$

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. How did you come up with this idea ? I mean how you found out that the two terms can be expressed as sin theta and cos theta ?

Answer (score 1):

Who says you're wrong? Observe that

$$2\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\beta-\alpha}} = \pi - 2\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{\beta - x}}{\sqrt{\beta - \alpha}}$$

under the assumption that $\alpha < x < \beta$. Since both functions differ only by a constant, they are both valid antiderivatives.

---

In case it is unclear consider that

$$(\sqrt{x-\alpha})^2 + (\sqrt{\beta - x})^2 = (\sqrt{\beta - \alpha})^2$$

form a valid pythagorean triple. In other words by SOH-CAH-TOA the two arcsine ratios (one for each leg over hypotenuse) must be complimentary angles

$$\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\beta-\alpha}} + \sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{\beta - x}}{\sqrt{\beta - \alpha}} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: How did you find out the two constants differ by pi ? Did you find out the Pythagorean triple pattern by only seeing the problem ? I just want to know how you found out the sum of two arcsine ratios is pi/2

Comment: @abcdefgh I found out they differed by $\pi$ by plugging in $x=\alpha$ in both. To prove it I used the Pythagorean triple. The rest is obvious trig, which you should practice if you could not see it right away.

Comment: Thanks @Ninad Munshi

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}, b>a$$
Let $x=a\sin^2t+b\cos^2t \implies dx= (a-b) \sin 2t$ then
$$I=2\int \frac{(a-b) \sin 2t dt}{|(b-a) \sin 2t|}=- 2 \arcsin\sqrt{\frac{b-x}{b-a}}$$

Comment: Yes this two will work.

Comment: Ok I got it Thank You @Z Ahmed But how did you come up with this idea of writing x=asin²t+bcos²t ?